# Prove that a triangle is right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I'd like to know if there's any theorem to prove that the triangle ACB' is a right triangle and that the angle ACB' is 90°.

[image]

We know that ACB and A'B'C'  are right triangles, so in my opinion ACB' is also a right triangle, but I don't know how to prove it

If there's any theorem or explanation please let me know.

Comment: A right angle and $90\unicode{xb0}$ are the same thing. I think it's true because it's an orthogonal projection.

Comment: You must also have $\angle ACC'=90°$ for that to be true. In that case, it is true by the properties of the normal line to a plane.

Comment: For a proof see Euclid's Elements, XI-4: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookXI/propXI4.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that is a right prism, we have that $\;CC'\perp\Delta ABC\;$  and since this last is a right triangle at $\;C\;$ , we then get that $\;AC\perp CBB'C'\;$ , as $\;AC\;$ is perpendicular to two different lines on that plane that go through the line's foot on the plane (point $\;C\;$ ) , namely: to $\;CC'\;$ and to $\;BC\;$ .

From here it follows that $\;AC\;$ **must** be perpendicular to any line contained in plane $\;CBB'C'\;$ and thus *also* to $\;CB'\;$ .

The above is just vector geometry in three dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

If we just have have to give a statement (not proving) that $\angle(ACB')=90°$ , You can say that:

Since the planes $ ACC'A'$ and $CBB'C'$ are perpendicular to each other,

$\implies $ Every line segment contained by $ACC'A' $ must also be perpendicular to line contained by $CBB'C$.

This way we interpret $AC$ perpendicular to $CB'$ or $\angle ACB' = 90° $

---

---

But as the question is not just giving the figure, but  **lengths of sides are also given** , it dictates us to use those given data, and prove in a much simpler way just using Pythagoras Theorem and its converse.

For **proving** $$ \angle ACB' = 90° $$
You will need **Converse of Pythagoras Theorem**, which states that *in any triangle, if the square of one side is equal to the sum of squares of other two sides, then the angle opposite to larger side (hypotenuse) is a right angle*

---

Please note one thing that $\color{green}{CC'B'B}$ is a rectangle.

(Which seems as a parallelogram in your $3D$ figure)

With $$BC= 8cm $$ and

$$BB' = √3$$

So, by Pythagoras Theorem, the diagonal of this rectangle, 
$$B'C = \sqrt{(BB')^2+ (BC)^2}$$
$$ = \sqrt{(√3)^2+(8)^2}$$
$$ = \color{green}{\sqrt{67}} $$

Now, diagonal of rectangle $ \color{red}{ AA'B'B } $
$$AB' = \sqrt{(AA')^2+ (A'B')^2}$$
 $$AB'  = \sqrt{(√3)^2+10^2}$$
$$ =\color{red}{ \sqrt{103}} $$

So $$ AB' = \sqrt{103},$$
$$ AC = 6 ,$$
$$CB' = (√67) $$

Therefore, In ($3D$) $∆AB'C$,

We see that,
$$ (AB')^2=(\color{red}{√103})^2=103 $$
& $$ AC^2+(CB)^2 $$ is also
$$ = (\color{green}{√67})^2+(6)^2=67+36=103 $$

Since, square of larger side (hypotenuse) $ AB' $ is equal to sum of squares of other two sides, namely, $ AC $ & $ CB' $.

And therefore by  **converse of Pythagoras Theorem** , we have,
$$\angle ACB' = 90° $$

Comment: @Arbri Ibra See the complete answer

Answer (score 2):

First, find the lengths of the triangle, but we do not need to find $AC$ because it is stated. To find $AB'$, find $AB$ first. $6^2+8^2=36+64=100=10^2$, so $AB$ is $10$cm. $10^2+\sqrt{3}^2=100+3=103=\sqrt{103}$, so $AB'$ is $\sqrt{103}$. $B'C$ is $\sqrt{8^2+3}=\sqrt{67}$ Taking these, we find that $AB'$ is longer than $AC$ and $AB'$, so $AC^2+AB'^2=AB'^2$ if $\angle ABC'$ is right (The Pythegorean theorem only works when the triangle is right). Taking these, we get: $\sqrt{67}^2+6^2=\sqrt{103}^2$, then $67+36=103$, then $103=103$. Therefore, $ABC'$ is a right-angle triangle.

Please note that $AA'$ has no unit, but I assumed it is $\sqrt3$.